# how can i trigger my widgets element with their prices

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have screen that have main service and another screen that has extra Service i want to trigger when the user select one it save it's price in somewhere(list or maybe thing better) and then show all the selected items name besides their prices at some screen in the end how can i do that here is my main service screen code as example

```
return SizedBox(
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: mainServices.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: MainServiceWidget(
          title: mainServices[index].name,
          subtitle:
              mainServices[index].service_description,
          price: mainServices[index].service_price,
          image: mainServices[index].service_image,
          isSelected: selectedServicesState
              .selectedServices
              .contains(mainServices[index]),
          onTap: () {
            print(selectedServicesState.selectedServices);
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

my state class

```
@freezed
class ServicesState<T> with _$ServicesState {
  // Declare T here
  const factory ServicesState.initial() = ServicesInitial;
  const factory ServicesState.loading() = ServicesLoading;
  const factory ServicesState.success(ServicesModel value) = ServiceSuccess;
  const factory ServicesState.failure(String error) = ServicesFailure;
}
```

my service cubit class

```
class ServiceCubit extends Cubit<ServicesState> {
  final ServicesRepo _servicesRepo;
  final List<Services> selectedServices = [];

  ServiceCubit(this._servicesRepo) : super(const ServicesState.initial());
 
  void emitServiceStates() async {
    emit(const ServicesState.loading());
    final response = await _servicesRepo.getServices();
    debugPrint('response: ${response}');
    response.when(success: (services) {
      emit(ServicesState.success(services));
    }, failure: (error) {
      emit(ServicesState.failure(error.apiErrorModel.message ?? ''));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: could you clarify description? and whay is selectedServicesState and mainServices?